# Eclipse/Tomcat configuration for updating resources on page refresh

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc, project-management, development-environment

I am working on a website written in java spring with maven.

I would like to use Notepad++ or some other external program other then eclipse to edit my js/html files. but i also need my server to be running, and always redeploying my resources when i refresh the browser.

right now if i work and edit the files from within eclipse, when ever i save a file the website is being redeployed and the refresh gives back the modified files. but if i use Notepad++ to edit the files, the server does not refresh them.

is there a way to make eclipse/tomcat always fetch the files from the server (like a no caching kind of configuration).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an option in Eclipse to poll files on the filesystem, making it aware of changes made to files by external editors.

The setting is located in the Eclipse preferences

> Preferences > General > Workspaces > Refresh using native hooks or
>   polling

It takes a second or 2 for Eclipse to pick up changes, and there most likely will be a performance penalty as it needs to poll your entire workspace on a regular basis but it should do the job.

It also works well with Servers configured in Eclipse that need to be republished when files are changed (cfr Tomcat Server)

Comment: I would like to comment that this does not work perfectly. sometimes you really need to wait again